# Ubuntu 10.04 Brightness stuck at 0 on my HP DV2000 Laptop.. How to change

Tags: display, ubuntu-10.04

I am Running Ubuntu 10.04 LTE on HP DV2000 Series Laptop. It was working good till last night. But today when I restarted it, I couldn't see a thing. It was all black screen, I can hear the harddisk spinning and it is working. Then after several times I hard rebooted it, finally it showed me the screen but with minimal brightness say like I can figure out what is what If I can stare at the monitor very long period. I have tried to update the linux kernel if that was the problem. But no. Currently i am running the same box by connecting a monitor to it.

What are the causes of this type of problem? And how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Some laptops have an issue with their backlight lamp and/or circuit going bad all of a sudden. I had similar issue with HP laptop 2 years ago, had to replace this part.

Comment: what part did you have to replace?

Comment: @mvp So its a hardware issue not a OS issue. Well I have to look for backlight lamp???.

Comment: If rebooting machine does not show visible BIOS messages, this is definitely hardware. Just buy this inverter part for $10 and replace it - it takes about 15-30 minutes to take your laptop apart and replace it. [This Youtube video](http://youtu.be/UT2GFVem_9U) should to be great guide for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen a huge number of issues with the inverter on the DV2000 models.  I can't say 100% that is your issue, but it sounds likely and it is it's fairly easy to replace (and cheap).

You'll need to remove the screen bezel (6 screws on the front of the display I believe). Then along the bottom is [this part](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B005M6B9OI). It's a few plugs and you're done.

Courtesy of Amazon:

[image]

Comment: +1 Bingo! This is the part I had to replace on my HP laptop.

Comment: @mvp A buddy and I fixed 10-12 of them for folks throughout college. Fortunately for the OP it's a fairly easy fix (I'm surprised iFixit doesn't have a teardown for it).

Comment: @nerdwaller will try . and update the results.